# Fastest way of USA to Pakistan Transacations

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms, payments, late-payment

I am working on a popular freelance website as a freelancer. I used to withdraw my funds by my Payoneer credit card for so long. In this way I received funds immediately. But the issue is that in this way charges of transfer are too high. I felt that almost 10%-15% payment deducts on every payment withdraw. I tried to receive money via bank. But that takes too long (more than 10-12 days). Is there any other way by which I could withdraw money with speed and low rate.

Answer (score 2):

Payoneer is the cheapest way around. Rates are Freelancers site's fees + 1% if you want immediate load + up to 3% Payoneer fees when you pay on POS. The latest fee is charged because dollar has left the USA :).

I have no idea how you came up to 10-15%.